# SimpleCV Error after reinstalling Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I'm not sure if it's a problem of SimpleCV or Ubuntu itself. Any hints? What is svgwrite?

```
ERROR: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/simplecv", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('SimpleCV==1.3', 'console_scripts', 'simplecv')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 351, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2363, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2088, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SimpleCV/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from SimpleCV.Camera import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SimpleCV/Camera.py", line 5, in <module>
    from SimpleCV.ImageClass import Image, ImageSet, ColorSpace
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SimpleCV/ImageClass.py", line 14768, in <module>
    from SimpleCV.DrawingLayer import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SimpleCV/DrawingLayer.py", line 5, in <module>
    import svgwrite
ImportError: No module named svgwrite
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a [known module dependency issue with SimpleCV](https://github.com/sightmachine/SimpleCV/issues/564). The suggested workaround from that GitHub thread is to install the missing svgwrite python module using `pip`

```
sudo pip install svgwrite
```